# How do you migrate a question?

Tags: support

Do I need a certain privilege to be able to migrate my (or someone else's) question to a different stack exchange site?

Answer (score 1):

Only moderators can migrate.  However, you can (I believe) vote to close and indicate that the question belongs on another site.

Alternately, If you can't vote to close, you can flag the question for moderator attention, and add a message explaining where you think it should go and why.

Comment: vote to close as off topic and say it belongs elsewhere is usually best. Flag and say why if the destination you are looking for isn't an option.